# Stopping a Thread / Threads calls interrupt on itself after crash?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am currently running a Thread from a Service to do some background work.
Now there is the possibility that the Thread crashes or I want to 
interrupt the thread from the Service. So how am I supposed to:

1. stop the Thread realiable, (hard)
2. catch exceptions and call the Service about the crash
3. handle InterruptedException if interrupted while sleep()
4. is Thread.isInterrupted a good way to detect if the Thread stopped?

What I have done so far is the following:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            doMyBackgroundWork();
            sleep();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ExceptionHandler.logAndSendException(e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        if(crashedListener != null){
            crashedListener.onThreadCrashed();
        }
    }
    LOG.i("Thread stops now.");
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        sleep(frequency);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //what to do here? it can happen because I stopped it myself 
    }
}
```

So at first I am running my Thread until it gets interrupted.
If any exception occurs, I want to start a new Thread, therefore
my Service implements a listener interface and I call it, once an
Exception is thrown. I know that catching everything is discouraged,
but I need to know if the Thread stops, without polling Thread.isAlive()
all the time.

Additionally to my four questions above:

- is my code reliable and does what I need?
- is it ok to call interrupt on the Thread itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this help you, make new thread for checking does exception thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually interrupting your own thread because the `catch` block is outside of the while loop. Therefore, any exception would stop execution immediately.

Interruption is essentially just a request (usually from another thread) to stop doing what you are doing. The thread is free to ignore it and keep doing what it is doing. Normally you have to throw an exception in response to an interrupt, or stop execution some other way such as just breaking from the loop (you need this around the `//what to do here?` comment). It so happens that some library methods are "responsive to interruption" meaning they will throw an exception if the thread is ever interrupted, such as `Thread.sleep()`, which you will most likely have in your `sleep` call.

I recommend picking Java Concurrency In Practice. Among the excellent concurrency material, there is a chapter on interrupts which is very helpful.

*EDIT*:
I would remove the code where you interrupt your own thread. You will also need to rethrow the InterruptedException as a runtime exception to get out of the execution loop. Usually people will create a new Exception that extends RuntimeException that is something like MyInterruptedException. You can then add it to the catch block around your loop so that you know when the thread was interrupted vs execution failed.

As a general example you can do something like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            // check for interrupts in the loop, or somewhere in the work method
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                throw new MyInterruptedException("Important thread interrupted.");
            }
            doMyBackgroundWork();
            sleep();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ExceptionHandler.logAndSendException(e);
        if(crashedListener != null){
            crashedListener.onThreadCrashed();
        }
    }
    catch(MyInterruptedException i) {
        LOG.i("Execution stopping because of interrupt.");
    }
}

private void sleep() {
    try {
        sleep(frequency);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new MyInterrptedException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far! I had also the problem that I was not able to stop my thread (as you stated out - I catched the InterruptedException *duh*) and ended with 4-5 Threads at the same time. I will now try your example. Give me some sec.

Comment: Since you mention multiple threads, I would also recommend using an `ExecutorService` instead of trying to manage them yourself. The executor can handle keeping a constant pool of threads, respawning them when they die etc.

Comment: Lets say I have an Executer with a pool size of 1. If I need to stop the thread and start another one, does the executer directly stop the thread? Are there any timing disadvantages?

Comment: The Executor will use the same tools to stop the thread as you would -- with an interrupt. I can't think of any disadvantages to using an Executor over a home-baked approach. There are many implementations of ExecutorService, and you can also write your own. I recommend looking at the Javadoc to see some of the standard ones you can create with different parameters or searching online.

Comment: Thanks for the help mvd!

Answer (score 0):

we have a nice and effective method called `stop()`(`Thread.stop(void):void`) which is deprecated, but it works and it's lovely.

Note that `stop()` throws `ThreadDeath` at the target thread which is not an exception(and it could any other `throwable` too), but an `Error`, so your code will not catch any signal about this.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (<<using_a_volatile_bool_type_is_better>>) {
             ...
        }
    }catch(Throwable t){/**/}/*use throwable instead of exception.*/}
}
```

Beside dear friend `stop()` we also have `pause()` method too, and it really pauses the target thread.

Not just one solution out there, but if it's really critical to keep thread run and run the emergency(or itself) just after any crash, you may run it as a separately app/process, plus get progress status(if any) that ensures you the target thread/app is not freezed(blocked,...)